# Push docker image to Google Container Registry failure on Mac

Tags: docker, gcloud, google-kubernetes-engine

I was trying to upload my image to Google Container Registry, but it return some error and I don't know how to troubleshooting.

```
$> gcloud docker -- push asia.gcr.io/dtapi-1314/web
The push refers to a repository [asia.gcr.io/dtapi-1314/web]
53ccd4e59f47: Retrying in 1 second
32ca8635750d: Retrying in 1 second
e5363ba7dd4d: Retrying in 1 second
d575d439624a: Retrying in 1 second
5c1cba20b78d: Retrying in 1 second
7198e99c156d: Waiting
6ca37046de16: Waiting
b8f2f07b3eab: Waiting
16681562a534: Waiting
92ea1d98cb79: Waiting
97ca462ad9ee: Waiting
unable to decode token response: read tcp 10.0.2.10:54718->74.125.23.82:443: read: connection reset by peer
```

I checked permission on my Mac.

```
$> gsutil acl get gs://asia.artifacts.dtapi-1314.appspot.com
```

It returned a list of correct permission.

I'd tested push on the cloud console, it works.

Does anyone have clue?
Thanks a lot if anyone could help. :)

---

**Other troubleshooting**

```
gcloud auth login
```

```
gcloud docker -- login -p $(gcloud auth print-access-token) -u _token https://asia.gcr.io
gsutil acl get gs://asia.artifacts.{%PROJECT_ID}.appspot.com
```

Add insecure-registry to dockerd startup command.

```
--insecure-registry asia.gcr.io
```

---

**Might be the same cause**

```
gcloud docker -- pull google/python
```

The error was

```
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/google/python/manifests/latest: read tcp 10.0.2.15:37762->52.45.33.149:443: read: connection reset by peer
```

docker server log

```
DEBU[0499] Increasing token expiration to: 60 seconds
ERRO[0500] Error trying v2 registry: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/....../python/manifests/latest: read tcp 10.0.2.15:37762->52.45.33.149:443: read: connection reset by peer
ERRO[0500] Attempting next endpoint for pull after error: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/....../python/manifests/latest: read tcp 10.0.2.15:37762->52.45.33.149:443: read: connection reset by peer
DEBU[0500] Skipping v1 endpoint https://index.docker.io because v2 registry was detected
ERRO[0500] Handler for POST /v1.24/images/create returned error: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/....../python/manifests/latest: read tcp 10.0.2.15:37762->52.45.33.149:443: read: connection reset by peer
```

---

Environment

- MacOS: 10.11.6
- Docker Toolbox (on MAC)
- Docker 1.12.3 (Git commit: 6b644ec, Built: Wed Oct 26 23:26:11 2016)

Answer (score 1):

The root cause was stupid, but I'd like to update this for anyone who see this question. I found when I attached my computer to company's WIFI. Then It would work (Still some reset). The cable network of my company is mysterious broken to Google Container Registry. The cable network works for all other services (google/youtube/mobile services) we used but broken to Google Container Registry.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a permission issue. Try running
`gcloud auth login`

I remember running into a similar issue and this helped.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Robert. :)
After I tried `gcloud auth login`, the result was still the same.
I tried `gsutil acl get gs://asia.artifacts.{%PROJECT_ID}.appspot.com`. It returned correct permission instead of Access Denied. Just wonder if there any other tool or log to check?